# Concerning functions and for loops; passing variables in functions within a loop

Tags: c++, function, loops

I am having trouble with my code. I am attempting to make a program that initializes a series of variables prior to a for loop, but when the variable is changed within the loop I want it to remain that value in which it has been changed to. I am trying to create a tic tac toe game that has string variables initialized to represent that place for which it will placed when the user chooses that cell number, and X or O. But, instead of "remembering" the previous turn, it just resets the grid and only shows the cell selection of X or O for that current loop. I declared my variables globally to all functions can pass them.

tl;dr: variables are being reset to their original assigned values contrary to the fact that I declare and initialize them outside of the loop.

Here's my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

string getCell();
string getSymbol();
void displayBoard(string c00,string c01,string c02,string c10,string c11,string c12,string c20,string c21,string c22);

string cell;
string xoro;
string line;
int menuchoice;
fstream file;
string c00,c01,c02,c10,c11,c12,c20,c21,c22;

int main(){

c00="-";
c01="-";
c02="-";
c10="-";
c11="-";
c12="-";
c20="-";
c21="-";
c22="-";

for (int i=1; i<=9; i++){

cout << "(1) Load previous grid" << endl << "(2) New Game" << endl;
cout << "Please enter one of the menu choices:  ";
cin >> menuchoice;

switch (menuchoice){  
case 1:
    file.open("savedgame.txt");
    if (!file){
        cout << "Error opening file";}
    while (file >> line){
        cout << line << endl;}
    file.close();
    break;

case 2:

    getCell();

    getSymbol();

    displayBoard(c00, c01, c02, c10, c11, c12, c20, c21, c22);

    break;

default:
    cout << "Please enter a valid Menu Choice.";

    }
}
}


string getCell(){

    do{
        cout << "Enter Valid Cell Name: ";
        cin >> cell;}
     while ((cell!="00")&&(cell!="01")&&(cell!="02")&&(cell!="10")&&(cell!="11")&&(cell!="12")&&(cell!="20")&&(cell!="21")&&(cell!="22"));

     return cell;}

string getSymbol(){

    do{
        cout << "Enter X or O: ";
        cin >> xoro;}
    while ((xoro != "O" && xoro != "o") && (xoro != "X" && xoro != "x"));

    return xoro;}

void displayBoard(string c00, string c01, string c02, string c10, string c11, string c12, string c20, string c21, string c22){

file.open("savedgame.txt");

        if (cell == "00")  
            c00 = xoro;
        else if (cell == "01")
            c01 = xoro;
        else if (cell == "02")
            c02 = xoro;     
        else if (cell == "10")
            c10 = xoro;     
        else if (cell == "11")
            c11 = xoro;     
        else if (cell == "12")
            c12 = xoro;     
        else if (cell == "20")
            c20 = xoro;     
        else if (cell == "21")
            c21 = xoro;     
        else if (cell == "22")
            c22 = xoro;


        cout <<"--"<<c00<<"--|--"<<c01<<"--|--"<<c02<<"--"<<endl<<"--"<<c10<<"--|--"<<c11<<"--|--"<<c12<<"--"<<endl<<"--"<<c20<<"--|--"<<c21<<"--|--"<<c22<<"--"<<endl;
        file <<"--"<<c00<<"--|--"<<c01<<"--|--"<<c02<<"--"<<endl<<"--"<<c10<<"--|--"<<c11<<"--|--"<<c12<<"--"<<endl<<"--"<<c20<<"--|--"<<c21<<"--|--"<<c22<<"--"<<endl;
        file.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have various issues with your code here. Starting with the most obvious one: Your program as shown here won't compile, at least it did not for me. You are using the operators cout and cin without using the  header. Also as pointed out you might want to use arrays, instead of x different variables that basically do the same. I also see no line in which you save the users input to the file, you just open it in displayboard(); likely the reason why your variables are not stored anywhere.

I would advise you to further look into arrays and how to manipulate the elements inside an array. It will make your code easier to read and maintain for you as well as others. Also you could use chars instead, as your cells won't go above one character. As such you could simply do:

```
char cell[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
cell[i] = '-';
}
```

Which gives you a 3*3 sized board. To manipulate the cells you simply ask the user for the cell and what type of character he wants to put in it. By doing so you can use one functions where you previously had two:

```
int cellname;
cout << "Enter a valid cell name";
cin >> cellname;
cout << "Enter X or O: ";
cin >> xoro;
cell[cellname] = xoro;
```

Another problem I just noticed in your code, in your first for loop, in which you ask the user the choose from the menu, you only let it repeat 9 times. If someone is typing 9 times the default menu choice, the program terminates. What you want is a while statement, that checks if the user input is greater than 0 or smaller than 3.